# How can i do my discord.py bot recognize multiple args as just one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to make my discord bot translate a message using web API, but when i execute the command it only uses the first arg (before space) or changing the code it only gets the last arg (after space)

here is my code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=False)
async def brus(ctx, args):
    useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession(headers={'User-Agent': useragent})
    yandexkey = 'secret key'
    translatebrus = await session.get("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?text=" + args + "&lang=en&key=" + yandexkey)
    translatebrusres = await translatebrus.json()
    translateresult = str(translatebrusres['text'][0]) #here is where i get the translated response
    embed4 = discord.Embed(title="BR-EN TRANSLATION", description=(translateresult), color=0x1aff00)
    await bot.say("", embed=embed4) #i just use this to send the message already formatted to embed
    await bot.say(translatebrusres) #unnecessary, just to see my response
    await bot.say(translatebrus) #unnecessary, just to see my request
    session.close()
```

and here is my response on discord:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFWet.png

on the image, you can see that "mundo" is the last arg, and the translation to english is "world", but "ola" that is the first args it doesn't translate

i have tried using *args, **kwargs, message and str but i didn't get any changes
i have seen other related posts on stackoverflow but none of them work for me

edit:
fixed it using

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True) #It was pass context FALSE
async def brus(ctx, *, traduzir): #It was using args, was changed to custom arg name (traduzir) and added * before custom arg name to translate all arguments as just one (what i wanted to do)
#and changed the session get to this
translatebrus = await session.get(f"https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?text={quote(traduzir)}&lang=pt-en&key=" + yandexkey #thanks Samuel, the quote was helpful, without quote it wont pass the arguments right to be json decoded.
```

thats it, hope i help someone else ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the information to solve this, but there are a few things I'm suspecting:

a) You specify `pass_context=False`, yet the first argument to your `brus` function is is `ctx`. Could it be that you are unintentionally always putting the first word inside `ctx`? You might want to use a debugger or print what `ctx` and `args` are.

b) The [Yandex documentation](https://tech.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/reference/translate-docpage/) has the following warning:

> Attention.
>
> The source text must be URL-encoded.

I'm suspecting the text you receive in "args" in just a regular string like `ola mundo`, so you might need to escape it and make it URL safe:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote
>>> quote('This is the text')
'This%20is%20the%20text'
```

If a) is actually the problem, I still suggest you add the `quote()` step, otherwise a lot of input will potentially break your bot!